# Information from xml to csv

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I want take information from xml file and insert it to file csv.

I make code with help of this forum:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Mateusz\\Desktop\\DublinCore.xml");
                var authors = doc.Descendants(dc + "subject");
                foreach (var author in authors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(author.Value);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Now this code take information from 1 file, but how make that take info from all xml files in directory?
I think i should use for/while to take info from first file, then from next, but i don't know how do it with `Xdoucment.Load` because its only to 1 file.

Comment: Loop over all the files in the directory with `Directry.GetFiles` or `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and use `Load` on each one.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
        const string Folder = @"C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach(string filename in Directory.GetFiles(Folder,"*.xml"))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
                XNamespace dc = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dc");
                var authors = doc.Descendants(dc + "subject");
                foreach (var author in authors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(author.Value);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            
        }
```